# Select Dropdown values based on input in textfield

Tags: html

I have a HTML form having IFSC field and bank name select field as given [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpmAP.png).

An IFSC code consists of 11 digit and first four digits are bank identifier. So  if somebody enters first four digits in input field, then `select` field should automatically show that bank name.

My code is as follows:

```html
<input name="ifsccode" type="text" maxlength="11" class="form-control" placeholder="IFSC&#32;Code" required/>


<select name="bankname" class="form-control" required>
  <option selected="selected" value="0">--Select --</option>
  <option value="1">ALLAHABAD BANK </option>
  <option value="2">ANDHRA BANK</option>
  <option value="3">AXIS BANK</option>
  <option value="29">STATE BANK OF INDIA</option>
  <option value="4">BANK OF BARODA</option>
  <option value="29">UCO BANK</option>
  <option value="29">UNION BANK OF INDIA</option>
  <option value="5">BANK OF INDIA</option>
  <option value="20">BANDHAN BANK LIMITED</option>
  <option value="7">CANARA BANK</option>
  <option value="32">GRAMIN VIKASH BANK</option>
  <option value="8">CORPORATION BANK</option>
  <option value="9">INDIAN BANK</option>
  <option value="10">INDIAN OVERSEAS BANK</option>
  <option value="11">ORIENTAL BANK OF COMMERCE</option>
  <option value="12">PUNJAB AND SIND BANK</option>
  <option value="13">PUNJAB NATIONAL BANK</option>
  <option value="14">RESERVE BANK OF INDIA</option>
  <option value="15">SOUTH INDIAN BANK</option>
  <option value="16">UNITED BANK OF INDIA</option>
  <option value="17">CENTRAL BANK OF INDIA</option>
  <option value="18">VIJAYA BANK</option>
  <option value="19">DENA BANK</option>
  <option value="21">BHARATIYA MAHILA BANK LIMITED</option>
  <option value="22">FEDERAL BANK LTD </option>
  <option value="23">HDFC BANK LTD</option>
  <option value="24">ICICI BANK LTD</option>
  <option value="25">IDBI BANK LTD</option>
  <option value="66">PAYTM BANK</option>
  <option value="29">FINO PAYMENT BANK</option>
  <option value="26">INDUSIND BANK LTD</option>
  <option value="27">KARNATAKA BANK LTD</option>
  <option value="28">KOTAK MAHINDRA BANK</option>
  <option value="30">YES BANK LTD</option>
  <option value="31">SYNDICATE BANK</option>
  <option value="5">BANK OF INDIA</option>
  <option value="6">BANK OF MAHARASHTRA</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you need is a bit of Javascript to detect what digits are being typed out into the `<input>` and select the apprpriate option in the `<select>`.

Comment: I suggest select2 with its embedded search field for select :https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Comment: you have not shown any of the `IFSC` codes nor explained how a 4-digit identifier for the bank correlates to the items depicted in the above `SELECT` menu. Can you clarify these things please?

Comment: suppose if i enter ifsc code SBIN0001459 where SBIN is bank identifier for STATE BANK OF INDIA, then i want to show only STATE BANK OF INDIA option only. with ajax or by php mysql query.

Comment: Ok, but how does `SBIN0001459` relate to the item in the select menu with value 29? Also - you said `"As ifsc code consists of 11 digit and first four digits are bank identifier"` ~ they are not all digits

Comment: sorry for that wording. But how it is possible to do the same where i am wrong.

Comment: Do you have all the IFSC codes and Bank details in a database?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Trick is, you need to set ifsc code as value in the option.

```js
var opsArr = [];

$('#bankname > option').each((index, ele) => {
    opsArr.push(ele.value);
});

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("ifsccode").value;
    if (x && x.length >= 4) {
        var ifsc = x.substr(0, 4);
        ifsc = opsArr.find(key => ifsc == key);
        $('select').val((ifsc) ? ifsc : opsArr[0]);
    } else if (x.length < 4) {
        $('select').val(opsArr[0]);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
Assume IFSC codes BAN19870001, BAN29870001, BAN39870001. Try below.
</p>


<input id="ifsccode" name="ifsccode" type="text" maxlength="11" class="form-control" placeholder="IFSC Code" oninput="myFunction()" required/>

    <select id="bankname" name="bankname" class="form-control" required>
        <option selected="selected" value="BANK">--Select --</option>
        <option value="BAN1">BANK NAME-1</option>
        <option value="BAN2">BANK NAME-2</option>
        <option value="BAN3">BANK NAME-3</option>
        <option value="BAN4">BANK NAME-4</option>
    </select>
```